# Link to original document

Tags: excel, vba

i need help. I found this code that is very useful in what I need, however, it lacks 2 things that I am not finding how to do. I needed the files that are read from the directory had the link of the location or be clicking in excel in each of them could be opened the part. Can help me?

```
Sub ListaArquivosDiretorio()
Dim strOrigem As String
Dim strExtensao As String

strOrigem = Range("origem")
strExtensao = Range("extensao")

'Coloca barra no final, caso nao exista
If Right(strOrigem, 1) <> "\" Then
   strOrigem = strOrigem & "\"
End If

'Apaga resultados anteriores
Range("B9:B1048576").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A1").Select

Range("B9").Select 'Inicia a selecao no primeiro arquivo

'Define a string de busca e extensão
strFile = Dir(strOrigem & "*" & strExtensao)

Do While strFile <> ""
    ActiveCell = strFile
    strFile = Dir
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but `I needed the files that are read from the directory had the link of the location or be clicking in excel in each of them could be opened the part` is not very clear. Can you revise this question to include more details

Comment: ok. with this code all the files in the "origem" directory are listed in column B.

AAAA
BBBB
CCCC

and in each of them I need them to have a hyperlink to open the file AAAA, BBBB ...

Comment: Alright, check out `Hyperlinks.Add` then, it shouldn't be too hard to adapt what you're working with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add